SharePoint online - Site owner full control but access denied on permission setting
In a SharePoint online site, site owner with full control on the site is getting Access denied error, when tried to access site permissions settings or click on page permissions though they have permissions with full control on the site owner group. If i add them to site collection admin, they have access. But can't provide that permission.
Any solution/ideas?
Thanks
Venkat
